# Html horizontal scroll wont move even so its showing

Tags: html, css, scroll

This is my html and css code.I am trying to have the effect like scrolling through pages horizontally . The Scrollbar is showing that its on half but it wont budge.
I am sure I am missing something really primitive any help?
Thanks in advance

```
            <div className='scroll-horizontal'>
            <div className='pages white'>
            </div>
            <div className='pages black'>
            <Models />
            </div>
            </div>
```

---css

```
             .scroll-horizontal{
             display: grid;
             grid-auto-flow: column;
             grid-auto-columns: 100%;
             gap: 5vw;
             overflow-x:auto;
             height: 100vh;
             white-space: nowrap;
             }

             .pages{
             width: 100vw;
             height: 100vh;
            display: inline-block;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code to be valid HTML and pasted it into the below snippet, it should work as expected.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.scroll-horizontal {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 100%;
  gap: 5vw;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.pages {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.white {
  background-color: aqua;
  color: white;
}

.black {
  background-color: #000;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='scroll-horizontal'>
  <div class='pages white'>
    Scroll left to go right
  </div>
  <div class='pages black'>
    Scroll right to go left
  </div>
</div>
```